# LXQT session font in Ubuntu 20.04 looks big

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, fonts, lxqt

I've just installed LXQT in my Ubuntu 20.04 and found that the font too big. I already tried to change the font size in the appearance settings but it doesn't work. How can i make the font smaller? I use an old Acer laptop with Nvidia 340 installed.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html  though a picture or more detail on what *font* you're talking about may allow more precise advice..  (*the Lubuntu manual assumes a Lubuntu session, the LXQt one doesn't use all Lubuntu's setup so not everything will work as documented in the manual; the LXQt session is a more pure upstream experience so look at their documentation*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution several days ago in the last post of this link: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/nvidia-proprietary-driver-ui-scaling-issue/38204/7

I did

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/nvidia.conf
```

Then edit the "screen" section by adding two options, "UseEdidDpi" "False" and "DPI" "96x96"

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Option "UseEdidDpi" "False"
        Option "DPI" "96x96"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Tried and this worked! In my case (Lubuntu 20.04 LXQT), after installing the Nvidia prop. driver and configured my multi-monitor, saved the settings to xorg.conf the file I needed to edit is not nvidia.conf but xorg.conf I just added the two options mentioned.